# how set dynamic height for combobox

Tags: extjs, height

Is there any way to set dynamic height of combobox. I got the problem that the combobox only show the first option of the list. I want to make the dynamic height to show many option in list. Below is my code:

```
xtype           : 'pet.filtermulticombobox',
                        hideOnSelect    : false,
                        name            : 'category',
                        triggerAction   : 'all',
                        emptyTextKey    : _('Categories'),
                        ref             : '../url',
                        store           : new Ext.data.Store({
                                            autoLoad: true,
                                            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url: '/url'}),
                                            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                                                totalProperty: 'total',
                                                root:'records'
                                            },
                                            [{name: 'id'}, {name: 'name'}, {name: 'name_en'}, {name: 'class'}])
                                          }),
                        valueField      : 'id',
                        minChars        : 3,
                        displayField    : 'name_en',
                        classField      : 'class',
                        mode            : 'local',
                        width           : 125,
                        listWidth       : 400,
                        typeAhead       : true,
                        listeners       : {
                            scope   : this,
                            select  : function() {
                                this.fireEvent('filter');
                            }
                        },
                        filter: {
                            anyMatch: true,
                            caseSensitive: true
                        }
```

Comment: combobox is for single selection, but multiple options can be shown in a dropdown for single selection.

For multiple selection combobox use superselectbox or similar widgets.

Comment: Can you post a demo of the problem at http://fiddle.sencha.com? Combo normally shows 6-12 items in the dropdown so I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Hi try to add this config to your combo. Here your are increasing the drop down's height there by you can see more options.

```
listConfig:{
        maxHeight:  //Give a value that suits your req. 
      }
```

If you want dynamically there is no setter method for this,so try the same in run time.It might work.

Refer the docs for further information.

Hope it helps you